# Kafka "no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)" Logs

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two kafka brokers and one of the brokers logs are like this and it get this logs continuously for days:

```
[2019-08-28 11:32:36,536] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1102583550: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:37,399] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 61357918: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:37,850] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 969882655: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:38,417] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 64421981: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:38,649] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 546400007: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:39,308] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1258965019: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:39,494] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 280358699: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:39,501] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 114060853: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:39,839] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1311406137: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:40,003] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 359266578: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:40,056] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1683589856: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:40,091] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 693885882: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:40,548] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1895183133: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:41,009] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 146591803: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,302] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1939088760: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,304] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 2113665337: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,376] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1754665666: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,402] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 582197916: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,494] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 736073903: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,494] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 750866896: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:42,612] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 324921869: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,011] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1409668082: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,022] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 318604941: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,180] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 184073434: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,196] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1885155713: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,516] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1384280357: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,674] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 58913555: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,715] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 442040703: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,729] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session id 1429411734: no such session ID found. (kafka.server.FetchManager)
[2019-08-28 11:32:43,972] INFO Created a new error FetchContext for session
```

But my system works fine. I can consume and produce data. What could be the reason of this?